# UITableView row insertion crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add Row/cell in to tableview, but before [Table  endUpdates]; ... app crashes with error :

*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:909
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 33 into section 0, but there are only 33 rows in section 0 after the update'

```
-(IBAction)createTask
{
    Data  *sharedManager = [Data sharedManager]; //singleton class
    [Table  beginUpdates];

    [Table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                          [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: 
                                                [sharedManager._NAME count] inSection:0]] 
                                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

     // sharedManager._NAME is NSMutableArray wich consists names for cells
    [Task_handler createTask]; // adds objects to NSMutableArray's 
                               // (like names for cels and so on)

    [Table  endUpdates];
    [Table reloadData];

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    Data  *sharedManager = [Data sharedManager];
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection : %d",[sharedManager._NAME count]);

    return [sharedManager._NAME count];
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you ricalculate the number of the row in the delegate method?

Comment: Yes, i do. I have updated my question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Crash was solved by changing code into:

```
Data  *sharedManager = [Data sharedManager];
[Table  beginUpdates];
[Table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                          [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: 
                                                [sharedManager._NAME count] inSection:0]] 
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[Task_handler createTask];
[Table  endUpdates];
```

Comment: so what's the difference between what you wrote in your question and this answer? you simply took out the `[Table reloadData]` part? please explain

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
-(IBAction)createTask
{
    Data  *sharedManager = [Data sharedManager]; //singleton class
    [Table  beginUpdates];
    [Table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: [sharedManager._NAME count]+1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [Task_handler createTask]; //adds objects to NSMutableArray's (like names for cels and so on)
    [Table reloadData];
    [Table  endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Reloading data is not needed and is not supposed to be called this way. I suppose the UITableView is complaining because he hasn't updated the number of elements or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

When adding rows to your table, you need to let the TableView know that it has more cells to manage.  Before using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`, you need to run the `[TaskHandler createTask]` method, which will create an object your datasource array.  That array should be an instance variable that is counted by your TableView delegate method `numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: I have moved up [TaskHandler createTask] and i get the same error :   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 6 into section 0, but there are only 6 rows in section 0 after the update'

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is you are passing in `[sharedManager._NAME count]` to the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` function.

Because you have 33 names, and rows start from index 0, you should be passing in `[sharedManager._NAME count] - 1`

The error is quite frankly misleading.